# How compare two int list, resultset?

Tags: sql

I have two list of integer in a resultset in a query, ex: List_1:  11,16,28... List_2 11,16,19..  How can I compare this two list in my Where condition?? The condition is if the list is different, make the select.

this is the code:

```
    SELECT cosechaAnterior.c_Fk_IdBoleta as 'BOLETA_P16', cosechaAnteriorDestino.c_Fk_IdBoleta as 'BOLETA_P17'
FROM Clt_CosechaAnterior cosechaAnterior
INNER JOIN  Clt_CosechaAnteriorDestino cosechaAnteriorDestino
ON cosechaAnterior.si_Fk_IdDesglose = cosechaAnteriorDestino.si_Fk_IdDesglose
INNER JOIN Blt_Boleta as boleta
ON cosechaAnterior.c_Fk_IdBoleta = boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta
WHERE  --boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta = 44990112--@id_boleta  
           (select si_Fk_IdDesglose
           from Clt_CosechaAnteriorDestino as cosechaAnteriorDestino
           where SUBSTRING(cosechaAnteriorDestino.c_Fk_IdBoleta,5,4) = '0112'
           AND cosechaAnteriorDestino.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 44990112)              (select si_Fk_IdDesglose
                                                                              from Clt_CosechaAnterior as cosechaAnterior
                                                                              where SUBSTRING(cosechaAnterior.c_Fk_IdBoleta,5,4)= '0112'
                                                                              AND cosechaAnterior.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 44990112)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this with a join, rather than in the WHERE clause.  It is a little unclear from your question what the two lists are.  So this answer gives a general solution.

Assume the lists are in a two-column format as (, ), where the list for  consists of multiple values.  Then the following query returns all ids that have exactly the same set of values:

```
select list1.id
from (<subquery 1>) list1 full outer join
     (<subquery 2>) list2
     on list1.id = list2.id and
        list1.val = list2.val
group by list1.id
having max(case when list1.id is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       max(case when list2.id is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

(This formulation assumes there are no duplications in the values.)

This is doing a full outer join and selecting only the ids that have no NULL values on either side of the join.  A NULL value is generated on a full outer join when elements do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx). If count of list_1 **except** list_2 is > 0, then you know the lists are different.

Comment: how's the syntax? to compare this two selects?

Comment: (SELECT ...) EXCEPT (SELECT ...)

Comment: If you are selecting only if the lists are different, you can do. SELECT ... WHERE ((list_1 select) EXCEPT (list_2 select) > 0)

Answer (score 0):

Treat each list as a text blob and use the function to test for equal on both text values.